# How do I set an image as a background in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a `<div style={styles.background}></div>`

Is it possible to do something like this?

```
import image from 'img/image.jpg';

const styles = {
  background: {
    background: `url(${image})`
  }
};

export default styles;
```

I know that won't work, but is there something similar to that?

Comment: React doesn't know anything about images. You can give it a regular image path (not using require/import) to where the image lives on the server. Are you using webpack? If so then you can require the image, see http://blog.andrewray.me/webpack-when-to-use-and-why/ for more information

Comment: You could, technically, convert the image to base64 and load it as a source as well. I did this to be able to explicitly embed an image once (but probably Andy Ray's comment is more applicable, I use webpack for all other images).

Comment: thanks.  so i should configure webpack to handle my assets folder, and then when i actually want to give the url to the image, how do I do that?

Comment: notice that the background property it nested twice.
could it be related to the problem?